# Symfony 5 and API-Platform 2.5 functional test for Not allowed method

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, api-platform.com

I have Symfony 5 and API-Platform 2.5, just installed with flex.
I created User entity as API Resource, the collection list must be forbidden, so I created a functional test to check it.

The test pass correctly but I get also an error:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --filter=UsersTest::testGetCollection
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
2020-05-03T21:50:50+00:00 [error] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: "No route found for "GET /api/users": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)" at /srv/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 140
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 691 ms, Memory: 30.00 MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

I Would like to hide the error message.

Here are the files:

#### User Class

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(collectionOperations={"post"}, itemOperations={"get"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
   /* some code */
}
```

#### Test

```php
class UsersTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

    /* some code */

    public function testGetCollection(): void
    {
        try {
            self::createClient()->request(Request::METHOD_GET, '/api/users');
            self::assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /* some code */
}
```

#### phpunit.xml.dist

```xml
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
    <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
    <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />
</php>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the code, look like you haven’t used the monolog library in your code. And you were right the RouterListener will print out the error messages in case you haven’t defined any loggerIterface(log driver) for your project. as soon as you install the `symfony/monolog-bundle` you will not see those ugly messages again.

Comment: Perfect, I installed monolog with **composer require symfony/monolog-bundle** and the error message disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$client = self::createClient();
$client->catchExceptions(false);
```

But I'll suggest using

```
$client = self::createClient(); 
$client->request(Request::METHOD_GET, "/api/users");
$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

instead of wrap the code with a try/catch

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case the $client->catchExceptions function does not exist, maybe it depends on the versions?  
  
In the other case, however, I get the error, I think it does not depend on the test code but on the code that is invoked by the test, in fact the exception is generated in:
/srv/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener /RouterListener.php line 140  
  
possible I can't handle it?

Comment: Maybe, I'm using version 4. That the framework error. As far as I know, you can't handle it. this is the framework error. But what is the problem with the above solution? And don't use try/catch. unless you are trying to run some unit tests.

Comment: Hi, no problem with above solution, just nothing changes, all tests pass but I still have the error.
I also prefer without try/catch, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you upload your project in GitHub maybe? I mean only that part which it throws the error.

Comment: Yes, you can see the project on https://github.com/fabiov/moneylog-api switch to develop branch

Comment: You need to install "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213118/discussion-between-fabio-and-mohammad-kaab).